# How to change the background of a Frame - Tkinter !?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have been creating an Frame using Tkinter in Python 2.7 and get a different Background!. However, when I use this code it gives the following error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bg"
```

and the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//MCLSERVER4/MCL Sicherung/M.Grbic/Python/Power Cycling Test/pwrMultiCycling.py", line 26, in <module>
    gui = Interface(root)
  File "//MCLSERVER4/MCL Sicherung/M.Grbic/Python/Power Cycling Test/pwrMultiCycling.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.frame = Frame(parent, bg='', colormap='new')
  File "S:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\ttk.py", line 735, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::frame", kw)
  File "S:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\ttk.py", line 555, in __init__
    Tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
  File "S:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2036, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bg"
```

and my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
import os
from PIL import Image

class Interface:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        parent.title("")
        local_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        self.dataname = "/does/not/exist"

        self.frame = Frame(parent, bg='', colormap='new')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    gui = Interface(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The dangers of * imports.

Comment: with that solution tk and ttk I can't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I have a solution and for my problem looks like this:

```
import Tkinter
from ttk import *
import os

    class Interface:

        def __init__(self, parent):
            self.parent = parent
            parent.title("")

            self.frame = Tkinter.Frame(parent, bg='', colormap='new')


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        root = Tkinter.Tk()
        gui = Interface(root)
        root.mainloop()
```